# Remove dictionary items in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to test which columns in df always have the same value, and remove them from the dictionary. However, even though both x1 and x2 should be removed, that does not happen.

```
data = [[0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.5], [0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.4, 0.3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'y1', 'y2']) 

vars1 = ["x1", "x2", "x3"]
vars2 = ["x1", "x3"]

vars_used = {"y1": vars1, "y2": vars2}

for ex_var in vars_used.get("y1"):
    if df[ex_var].value_counts(normalize=True).values.max() > np.float(0.999):
        vars_used.get("y1").remove(ex_var)

vars_used["y1"]
```

The output I get is ['x2', 'x3'], not ['x3']. If I use the same code outside a loop, it works fine. Looking for a simple solution for the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem:**

```
for ex_var in vars_used.get("y1"):
    print(ex_var)
    if df[ex_var].value_counts(normalize=True).values.max() > np.float(0.999):
        vars_used.get("y1").remove(ex_var)

x1
x3
```

**as you can see x2 is never tested, this happens because you remove x1 inside the loop**

> You can do:

```
remove_list=[]
for ex_var in vars_used.get("y1"):
    if df[ex_var].value_counts(normalize=True).values.max() > np.float(0.999):
        remove_list.append(ex_var)

[vars_used.get("y1").remove(key) for key in remove_list]
vars_used["y1"]
```

Output:

```
['x3']
```

---

> an elegant solution:

```
same_value=[*df.columns[df.nunique().eq(1)]]
print(same_value)

['x1', 'x2']
```

---

```
for key in vars_used:  
    for value in same_value: 
        try:
            vars_used[key].remove(value)
        except:
            pass

print(vars_used)

{'y1': ['x3'], 'y2': ['x3']}
```

Comment: I'm glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this, you know if there is only 1 unique value in the column then they are all repeats:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if len(df[col].unique())==1:
        vars_used['y1'].remove(col)

vars_used

{'y1': ['x3'], 'y2': ['x1', 'x3']}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.